# pipe (%>%) ggplot2 like ggvis

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, magrittr

When I integrate tables and figures in a document using `knitr`, adding the code makes it more reproducible and interesting.

Often a combination of `dplyr` and `ggvis` can make a plot that has relatively legible code (using the `magrittr` pipe operator `%>`).

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, am) %>%
  summarise( weight = mean(wt) ) %>%
  ggvis(x=~am, y=~weight, fill=~cyl) %>%
  layer_bars()
```

The problem is that the ggvis plot:

[image: ggvis]

does not look quite as as pretty as the ggplot2 plot (I know, factoring of `cyl`):

[image]

However, for `ggplot2` we need:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, cyl) %>%
  summarise( weight = mean(wt) ) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=am, y=weight, fill=cyl) ) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

My problem is that this switches from `%>%` to `+` for piping. I know this is a very minor itch, but I would much prefer to use:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, cyl) %>%
  summarise( weight = mean(wt) ) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=am, y=weight, fill=cyl) ) %>%
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Is there a way to modify the behaviour of `ggplot2` so that this would work?

ps. I don't like the idea of using `magrittr`'s `add()` since this again make the code more complicated to read.

Comment: Does it bother you that you have to type one character instead of three?

Comment: As I mention in the first sentence, its for a reproducible document. I am afraid that switching this makes it confusing for readers who are less familiar with R.

Comment: Can't you write your own wrapper around ggplot? something like: `geom_barw<-function(DF,x,y,fill,stat){return(ggplot(DF,aes_string(x=x,y=y,fill=fill)) + geom_bar(stat=stat))}`

Comment: @Mitra thanks, I tried this but cannot get it to work. But this would be a good solution yes.

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, but just use two different code chunks, one that uses the `%>%` operator, but doesn't get evaluated, and one that uses `+` but doesn't get echoed. I'd normally not recommend this since it voids the reproducibility of the code, but if you're willing to overwrite functions and build wrappers, my assumption is that you're not overly concerned with them running the code anyway.

Comment: I usually put curly braces around the whole `ggplot2` part.

Comment: @brittenb thanks, that is always a last resort yes. I would prefer to actually run the code though.

Comment: @Axeman thanks that is a good idea. I was playing around with the ggplot2 package and saw that `%+% <- +`. I tried to include `%>%.gg <- +`, but this does not seem to work. But `%+%` is almost the same as `%>%`, so perhaps I'll just use that.

Comment: Yeah there are `methods(\`+\`)` but no `methods(\`%>%\`)`. But I feel braces are more transparent than introducing wrappers, and make things reproducible. You do need the `.` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it would be too long to expand in the comments, and based on your answer I am not sure if you tried the bit of code I provided and it didn't work or you tried previously and didn't manage

```
geom_barw<-function(DF,x,y,fill,stat){
   require(ggplot2)
   p<-ggplot(DF,aes_string(x=x,y=y,fill=fill)) + geom_bar(stat=stat)
   return(p)
}
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl, am) %>%
summarise( weight = mean(wt) ) %>%
geom_barw(x='am', y='weight', fill='cyl', stat='identity')
```

This works for me with:
dplyr_0.4.2   ggplot2_2.1.0 magrittr_1.5

Of course `geom_barw` could be modified so you don't need to use the quotes anymore.

**EDIT**: There should be more elegant and safer way with `lazy` (see the [lazyeval](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/index.html) package), but a very quick adaptation would be to use `substitute` (as pointed by Axeman - however without the `deparse` part):

```
 geom_barw<-function(DF,x,y,fill,stat){
    require(ggplot2)

    x<-substitute(x)
    y<-substitute(y)
    fill<-substitute(fill)

    p<- ggplot(DF,aes_string(x=x,y=y,fill=fill))
    p<- p + geom_bar(stat=stat)
    return(p)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try to run the code from your comments, but that did not seem to work. This does indeed work very nicely. How would you modify `geom_barw()` to not use quotes? Presumable that is why I couldn't get the one from the comments to work.

Comment: If you want to use bare variable names you could `deparse(substitute())` them. Or look in to the `lazyeval` package and `aes_`.